# Liferay using PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, content-management-system, liferay

How can use of database PostgreSQL in Liferay and connection therewith, reading, programming in the VM to display contents of the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are following two way using which you can change liferay database.

At start up liferay provides the option using which we can change liferay database. 
Following is the steps for the same.

1.1) Create a database in  postgresql(like lportal).

1.2) Select the change database option at liferay start up.

1.3) Enter your databse url,username and password.

1.4) To run the liferay setup again you just need to change the following property in portal-setup-wizard.properties((check attached screen shot for path of this file)
        Change the following value false to true

**setup.wizard.enabled=true**

1.5) When you will run the sever it will ask you for the admin user configuration and exactly below that there is option to change the database using which you can change the database.

**OR**

You can create a file with name **portal-ext.properties** in Liferay root folder(check attached screen shot).

Add following database configuration.

```
#
# Postgresql
#
jdbc.default.driverClassName= Postgre Drive
jdbc.default.url= Database url
jdbc.default.username= database username
jdbc.default.password= database password
```

For more details check following url
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Portal+Properties

[image]

Hope it may help you.!!

Comment: ...and don't forget to put the database driver jar file in tomcat/lib/ext or whatever location you need/prefer for the appserver's global classpath.