# How to add postgresql Driver in liferay?

Tags: postgresql, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

I am trying to save the data in my db (already saving it in lportal). For that i created a connection file and wrote all the required code. Like we do in JDBC. I am able to store the data in lportal(default one) but when I tried to save it in my db.
I am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver cannot be found by ""
```

I tried adding the JAR to the folder but still the same thing. In JDBC we can add the JAR in lib folder but it doesn't seem to work here.

I also tried adding the jar to the tomcat bundle in lib and lib/ext folder but nothing seems to happen.

I also added the following line in my build.gradle file but no results.

```
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.25'
```

Can someone help regarding this as where and how to add JAR or any other file so that I can save the data in db at the same time as lportal.

**EDIT 1:**

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver cannot be found by my.registration.form_1.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at my.registration.form.portlet.DatabaseConnection.initializeDatabase(DatabaseConnection.java:16)
    at my.registration.form.portlet.RegistrationDAO.addOrganization(RegistrationDAO.java:14)
    at my.registration.form.portlet.MyRegistrationFormPortlet.addOrganization(MyRegistrationFormPortlet.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:189)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:415)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:97)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:260)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:77)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:564)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:610)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:299)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.processAction(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:490)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$processAction$0(PortletContainerImpl.java:148)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:395)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:346)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:174)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._processActionPerform(PortalRequestProcessor.java:706)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:646)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:194)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.process(MainServlet.java:1067)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:598)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:372)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:360)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:260)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:263)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**EDIT 2:**

My connection class

```
package my.registration.form.portlet;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnection
{
     protected static Connection initializeDatabase()throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
     {
         String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
         String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_lportal";
         String user = "user";
         String password = "password";
  
         Class.forName(driver);
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        
         return conn;
     }
}
```

DAO:

```
public class RegistrationDAO
{
    public static void addOrganization(long OrganizationId, String organizationName, long countryId) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.initializeDatabase();
        
        String query = "insert into organization(OrganizationId, organizationName, countryId) values(?,?,?)";
        
        try
        {           
            PreparedStatement prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            
            prestmt.setLong(1, OrganizationId);
            prestmt.setString(2, organizationName);
            prestmt.setLong(3, countryId);
            
            System.out.println("Organization Added Successfully in my_lportal Database !!");
             
            prestmt.executeUpdate();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@ProcessAction(name = "addOrganization")
        public void addOrganization(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException
        {
            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
            
            long UserId = themeDisplay.getUserId();     
            String organizationName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "organizationName");
            String country = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "country");
            String type = "organization";
            long countryId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "countryId");
            long statusId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "statusId");
            
            try
            {      // For storing in lportal(default)

                Organization organization = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization
                                            (
                                                UserId, 0, organizationName, type, 0,
                                                countryId, 12017, null, false, null 
                                            );
                _log.info("Organization Added Successfully !!");
                
                   // For storing in my database
                long OrganizationId =  organization.getOrganizationId();    
                
                RegistrationDAO.addOrganization(OrganizationId, organizationName, countryId);
                _log.info("Organization Added Successfully in my_lportal Database !!");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
```

Comment: That is what I mean. You need to learn how to ask questions precisely. As far as I can see you want to have an other database used in you portlet as for your server. Thats important to know. Can you share your code via Github or Gitlab? It could be that your code wants to load the driver with a "wrong" classLoader. Here you can see how to deal with multiple datasources. https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018160911-Connecting-Service-Builder-to-External-Data-Sources

Comment: Really Sorry if I am not able to make myself clear, Yes I want to store the data in lportal(default one) and in another DB(in postgres only) which I have created. I dont use Github, So I'll add my code here. Please tell where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Hm I am bad in topics like class loader but you define a static method for creating the connection. Therefore the Java class loader(?) is used and not the portal class loader. Let me check a few thing I need to try this by my own and I will come back to you.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please let me know the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your question is very confusing. So you want to use a PostgreSQL for your Liferay Portal right?
You configured everything correctly and downloaded the driver from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.4.1.jar?

Just put this driver in tomcat/lib not ext (maybe it is not configured to load). Restart the server.

Please provide the complete startup log output.

**EDIT1:**

Ok now I see what is wrong. Your gradle file need to compileInclude instead of compile the lib. The scope compile is only for compilation phase but you also need the library during runtime in the portlet so thats why you need to compileInclude it.

OSGI is a bit tricky when it comes to dependencies because you will get errors after this compileInclude. The portlet will tell you that there are missing dependencies. You can put them to an ignore list.

build.gradle - add line

```
compileInclude group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.4.1'
```

You need to put some packages to not import them in the bnd.bnd file. Just copy the Import-Package part. It needs to be copied in exact this way!

```
Bundle-Name: test-redirect-jsp
Bundle-SymbolicName: test.redirect.jsp
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package: test.redirect.jsp.constants
Import-Package:\
!com.sun.jna*,\
!org.osgi.service.jdbc*,\
!waffle.windows.auth*,\
*
```

The driver class should now be available during runtime.

MyTest

```
public class StaticTest {

    public static void test() {
        String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println(c.getName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Called

```
@ProcessAction(name = "addOrganization")
public void addOrganization(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {
    StaticTest.test();

}
```

Please be adviced that my and your solution are very dirty. This is not how it would be done and recommended. The clean way would be setup a second datasource via properties and build your external entities via service builder.

Again - please refer to https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018160911-Connecting-Service-Builder-to-External-Data-Sources

Comment: I followed your suggestion and added it in the lib folder of my tomcat bundle still the same error. Then I downloaded the the JAR from the link you provided same error again. I have included the stack trace in the question please have a look.

Comment: thank you !! it worked. And will surely go through the link which you provided and try to do it the proper way, But for now this works.

Comment: Great! Please think about your questions twice to precise them. If you provide more information you will get better and faster help.

Comment: Sure will try to do so, Again can't thank you enough you have been of great help !!

Answer (score 0):

At start up liferay provides the option using which we can change liferay database. Following is the steps for the same.

1.1) Create a database in postgresql(like lportal).

1.2) Select the change database option at liferay start up.

1.3) Enter your databse url,username and password.

You can create a file with name portal-ext.properties in Liferay root folder(check attached screen shot).

Add following database configuration.

## Postgresql

jdbc.default.driverClassName= enter driver

jdbc.default.url= enter URL

jdbc.default.username= enter UserName

jdbc.default.password= enter Password

Comment: thanks !! for the response. I have already done that and I can store the data in lportal DB now I want to add the data simultaneously to the lportal DB and my custom DB which I have created, While storing the data in my DB I am encountering the above problem. Can you please help with that ??

Comment: Is this answer partially stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916406/liferay-using-postgresql? If you provide settings it would be appreciated that you deliver detailed information - for example the driver class.